# Unable to change desktop environment with Lightdm in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: lightdm, mate, ubuntu-mate, 20.10, i3-wm

I just shifted to `Ubuntu Mate 20.10`. I prefer to use `i3` as my window manager. However I am unable to login into `i3` through `lightdm`!

Even if I select `i3` from the gear icon on the login screen, it keeps logging into `Mate`. It's been frustrating.

I tried the obvious

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

but that doesn't work!

So I suspect some config file in `usr/share/lightdm` or `.dmrc` is to be blamed for this behavior! I have tried tinkering around and changed `mate` to `i3` on some of these files. But it has not worked so far!

Please help.

p.s.: just-venting-out: Why do Distros do this?! :(

Comment: Please add output of `ls /usr/share/xsessions` and `dpkg -l | grep i3` to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the discovered behavior on fresh Ubuntu MATE 20.10 VM.
I have reported [bug 1910279](https://pad.lv/1910279) to LaunchPad.

As a workaround you have to remove [Arctica Greeter](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-groovy-gorilla-release-notes/) by:

```
sudo apt autopurge arctica-greeter
```

then install Slick Greeter back with

```
sudo apt-get install slick-greeter
```

then apply green MATE theme from Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS to it by executing long single command

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/31_ubuntu-mate.gschema.override
[x.dm.slick-greeter]
background='/usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntu-mate-common/Green-Wall-Logo.png'
background-color='#3C3B37'
draw-grid=false
draw-user-backgrounds=false
enable-hidpi='auto'
font-name='Ubuntu 11'
icon-theme-name='Ambiant-MATE'
high-contrast=false
show-hostname=true
#logo=Logo file to use
onscreen-keyboard=false
#other-monitors-logo=Logo file to use for other monitors
# play-ready-sound=A sound file to play when the greeter is ready
screen-reader=false
show-power=true
show-a11y=true
show-keyboard=true
show-clock=true
show-quit=true
theme-name='Ambiant-MATE'
xft-antialias=true
xft-dpi=96
xft-hintstyle='hintslight'
xft-rgba='rgb'
EOF
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

then reboot and login to i3 session.

Also I would recommend to revert all manual changes, which you have done.
All system files are controlled by APT and your method is incorrect.

---

Notes:

1. to revert the above customization use `sudo rm /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/31_ubuntu-mate.gschema.override; sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas ; sudo apt-get install arctica-greeter`.
2. for longer support and to decrease number of surprises I would recommend to install Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS with 5-year support instead of 9-months-supported 20.10.